# A general way of comparing constructors of two terms in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Given two terms t1 t2 of some data type, is there some way to check if t1 and t2 start with the same constructor, without doing some exhaustive case or pattern matching over constructors? Like if my type is Either a b, then I want

```
checkConst (Left x) (Left y) = True
checkConst (Right x) (Left y) = False
...
```

and so on without actually doing that pattern matching, and in a way that is generalizable to other types with on the order of 10 constructors. Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could use [Prisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) from the [Lens package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4) for that, might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for the generics functionality available in the `Data.Data` module.  If you define a data type with a derived `Data` instance, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
data Foo = Bar1 Int
         | Bar2 String String
         | Bar3 Double
         deriving (Data)
```

then you can retrieve the constructor for a value with `toConstr`:

```
> toConstr (Bar1 1)
Bar1
> toConstr (Bar2 "hello" "there")
Bar2
>
```

These are values of type `Constr` that can be compared for equality, so you can define:

```
checkConst :: (Data g) => g -> g -> Bool
checkConst x y = toConstr x == toConstr y
```

and get:

```
> checkConst (Bar1 10) (Bar1 20)
True
> checkConst (Bar1 10) (Bar3 20)
False
>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use some kind of intermediate type which can uniquely distinguish each constructor and has an `Eq` instance. For example, you could use an `Int` to distinguish each data constructor, and then compare the values.

```
checkConst x y = toInt x == toInt y
  where
    toInt (Left _)  = 1 :: Int
    toInt (Right _) = 2
```

If your type implements [`Data`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data) from `Data.Data`, you could use [`toConstr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#v:toConstr) to use [`Constr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Constr) as your intermediate type. In the case of `Either` this isn't necessary because you could use `isRight x == isRight y`, but for a data type with 10 constructors, this would be cleaner.